# WebSphere MQ SSL in SVRCONN channels in C++ application

Tags: c++, ssl, ibm-mq

We have a C++ application connecting as client to WebSphere MQ using configurable queue manager and queue name. We have been asked to migrate to SSL channels for security reasons. So far we have taken care of configuring Sender and Receiver channels to use SSL.

1. Do we need to move the SVRCONN channels as well to use SSL?
2. If yes, how do we provide key-store details in code to connect to channel?

I could not find any option in MQOPEN API to provide.

Answer (score 1):

> I could not find any option in MQOPEN API to provide.

Its not in MQOPEN but rather MQCONNX API call.  It is far better to use a CCDT (Client Channel Definition Table) file because then your code just needs to issue an MQCONN API call.